# html5 application cache not getting initiated

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, caching, application-cache

I have a the simplest html page which i have hosted on a spring application on  appache tomcat server . http://10.10.1.143:9999/abcApp/launch.lc .

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html manifest="http://10.10.1.143:9999/abcApp/EpubCachManifest.appcache">
<head>
    <title>Listening For Cache Events From The Application Cach</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
ssds
</body>
</html>
```

when the page loads on the chrome browser it dosent initiate the manifest download process.I can see other online hosted samples loading in the console with the message

Document was loaded from Application Cache with manifest  https://www.dartlang.org/samples/appcache/example/appcache.mf (index):1 Application Cache Checking event (index):1 Application Cache NoUpdate event

But my html page dosent seem to load the cache manifest in the first place.I have put a debug point on the request mapping of the manifest file to check but it never seem to hit the server for the manifest file.The path locations are fine!

Following are the requaet headers for the request from the browser

```
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:1203
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie:JSESSIONID=949C3BFA5920987384D90FC8A7FAEE4E; MoodleSessionTest=sUALILX2fr; MoodleSession=da932a052a9294b402d2c3d8259831d1; MOODLEID1_=%25F2a6%2590IyYZx%2525t
Host:10.10.1.143:9999
Origin:http://10.10.1.143:7878
Referer:http://10.10.1.143:7878/mod/basiclti/launch.php?id=147
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.111 Safari/537.36
```

and the response headers :::

```
Cache-Control:public,max-age=3600
Content-Language:en-US
Content-Length:309
Content-Type:text/html;charset=UTF-8
Date:Thu, 19 Feb 2015 08:37:02 GMT
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
Set-Cookie:JSESSIONID=9C2E560FC1E7F12CBAE7EE471C855E09; Path=/loudbooks; HttpOnly
```

May be i have a stupid miss but i am going mad over this.Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the response header needs to be "Cache-Control:public,max-age=3600" to enable caching in the first place.
Also this is out of the blue but anyone starting with using application caches should definitely start by reading [this](http://alistapart.com/article/application-cache-is-a-douchebag) . realized a lot of problems by using it.finally managed to achieve the intended result.